# JPA property java.net.URL

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

HI,

I have an object which has a piece of URL-Information associated with it.
Currently I save this URL in a simple String property, but java.net.URL would
provide me with additional goodies such as detection of malformed URLs etc.

On the other hand I would consider it very ugly, if JPA simply created a LOB for the URL-Object. Does anyone know how a property of the type java.net.URL will be persisted to
the database by compliant JPA providers?

Comment: I don't think the JPA spec provides for this. Which implementation are you using?

Comment: e.g. Hibernate has JPA extensions for this

Comment: e.g DataNucleus has JPA (and JDO) extensions for this (and many other standard types)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the JPA spec:

> The persistent ﬁelds or properties of
>   an entity maybe of the following types:
>   Java primitive types;  java.lang.String;
>   other Java serializable types
>   (including wrappers of the primitive
>   types,  java.math.BigInteger,
>   java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Date, 
>   java.util.Calendar[7], java.sql.Date,
>   java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp, 
>   user-deﬁned serializable types, byte[],
>   Byte[], char[], andCharacter[]);
>   enums; entity  types and/or
>   collections of entity types; and
>   embeddable classes (see section
>   2.1.5).

Plus the support for collections. But no primitive support of `URL`. They would however be supported as `Serializable`, which I guess would result in a LOB as you mentioned.

But you should be able to easily circumvent that: you can have the URL as a `String` in a field and a getter/setter that convert from `String` to `URL` though. Then you map the field with the annotation.

Or the opposite: the `java.lang.URL` in a field, and getter/setter to convert from `URL` to `String`, then you map the getter/setter with the annotation. I think it works as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use JPA `AttributeConverter` such as explain [here](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) to map a `URL` object into a `String` column (Hibernate does that out of the box)

Or, if you are only interrested in validation, you may use BeanValidation. There is a `@URL` annotation in HibernateValidator extension you can also create your own constraint such as explain [here](http://www.javabeat.net/bean-validation-java-ee-creating-custom-constraints-validations/)

I personnaly prefer the BeanValidation solution because considering url as `java.net.URL` bring some complexity : need for JPA `AttributeConverter`, JSF `Converter`, JAXB `Adapter`... while it is just for validation