# Hibernate - How to store java.net.URL into a database through Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a field `URL countryURL;` in a `Country` class. I want to store its data into a `COUNTRY` table in a database through Hibernate.

Which Hibernate `type` I should use in the hibernate mapping file

```
<property column="COUNTRY_URL" name="countryURL" type="..."/>
```

It is not excepting `string` and `text` type.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355260/jpa-property-java-net-url/2355298#2355298

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `org.hibernate.UserType` for URL which maps to a varchar column. See [Custom value types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom) in the reference documentation.

Comment: Your link has died :( .

Answer (score 5):

You could write your own user type, but it might be easier to perform the conversion `String`<->`Url` in property getters and setters:

```
private void setRawUrl(String s) {
    this.url = new Url(s);
}

private String getRawUrl() {
    return url.toString();
}
```

and map the property `rawUrl` with type `string`.

Answer (score 4):

it seems that there is for some times now a dedicated basic value type provided by Hibernate himself : [org.hibernate.type.UrlType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-basic-value-url)

Answer (score 0):

I'd store it as `String`. No need to make your life harder by implementing a custom type. That is, change `URL` to `String`in `Country`.

Comment: You mean that I should change the datatype of `countryURL` field in the `Country` class from `URL` to `String`

Comment: or you want to say what @meriton had mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.. storing as String doing conversion our self is wrong by OOAD approach.. Once it is a string user can always give any string, which may not be URL.. better to use Custom T