# How to mapping a list of java.net.URL with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I try:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
protected List<URL> urlList;
```

But I get error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
 bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource
 [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or
 @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:
 my.package.MyModel.urlList[java.net.URL]
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438387/hibernate-how-to-store-java-net-url-into-a-database-through-hibernate) answers, but I can't mapping list of URLs.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to map list of java.net.URL?

Comment: How is a URL an Entity???? A OneToMany is for a relation to an Entity. You don't have that. Read any decent JPA tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Using an `ElementCollection` and `CollectionTable` is the way to map a Collection of NON-ENTITY elements.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="MY_URLS")
Collection<URL> urlList;
```

Then it would depend on whether your JPA provider supports persistence of that element type (`URL`) out of the box. My provider (DataNucleus) does. You always can use `AttributeConverter` if it doesn't

Comment: Feel free to ACCEPT this answer when you realise that it does what you asked for

Answer (score -1):

What version of Hibernate are you using? Also, in your database, what is the datatype of the column; is it varchar, or something else?

From what I am understanding, it looks like your issue is that Hibernate does not know how to translate the column in the database to the java.net.URL class, a Hibernate type would need to be defined to tell Hibernate how to handle this conversion.

It looks like Hibernate does have a built-in type that should handle this conversion, assuming you are using a version of Hibernate that has it -- 3.6 or greater, I think.

Try adding this annotation to your List:

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UrlType")
```

If your version of Hibernate does not have org.hibernate.type.UrlType or if your database column data type is not a varchar, you will need to create a custom Hibernate type that defines what Hibernate needs to do to convert whatever data type in the database to a java.net.URL and back. Let us know if it gets to that point and we can give you more information.