# JPA Metamodel generation missing attributes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, metamodel, criteriaquery

I'm using JPA metamodel generation 
http://relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateStaticMetamodelGeneratorAnnotationProcessor
to be able to execute criteria queries with names of the attributes.

I'm generating the metamodel classes trough ANT and hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.5.Final
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen/4.3.5.Final

THE PROBLEM IS: 
If i have an entity like this:

```java
@Entity public class Order 
{
    @Id 
    Integer id;
    @ManyToOne 
    Customer customer;
    @OneToMany 
    Set<Item> items;
    BigDecimal totalCost;
    java.net.URI uri;
    ...
}
```

with setters and everything...

The metamodel generated will be like this:

```java
@StaticMetamodel(Order.class)
public class Order_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, Integer> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, Customer> customer;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<Order, Item> items;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, BigDecimal> totalCost;
}
```

So the **URI** is missing in the generated class.

Maybe it's because of the missing standard no attribute constructor for the java.net.URI?

THANKS!

Comment: Maybe it's just not supported by Hibernate's metamodel generator. It certainly is by DataNucleus metamodel generator AFAIK

Comment: This might be a Hibernate bug. Try explicitly mapping the `uri` field with a `@Basic` annotation.

Answer (score 9):

Use the @Basic annotation to annotate the field. You may have to provide an attribute converter.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355260/jpa-property-java-net-url) thread. You should map String to / from java.net.URI in getter / setter methods.